# Webpack's done time is much longer when compilation time

Tags: javascript, webpack

Can anybode explain me, why webpack prints such information at the end of building proccess:

```
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 7848 ms
Done in 20.29s.
```

Compiled in 8 seconds, but spent 20. What could be the reasons for this?